# level surface - question from mathematics analytics 2

Tags: calculus

Can someone help me with this exercise? I don't know how to solve it.

Consider the function $f:Df ⊂ \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^3-y}}-e^{z-x}$.

The graphic of the function  $g: Dg ⊂ \mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, $g(x,y) = x - \ln(\sqrt{x^3-y})$ is a level surface  $c$ of the function  $f$, for which value from $c$?

Comment: Isn't $g: Dg \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Set $f(x,y,z)=0$ and extract $z=...$ under the form $z=\gamma(x,y)$ ; you will be surprized to find back $g(x,y)$...

Comment: The function is Dg⊂R3→R3 . Jean Marie, thanks for the answer but why i need to extract z? My inicial thought to solve this exercice was to do f(x,y,z) = k and k =g(x,y) . Why is this incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is merely pointing out that [Ovi](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/64460/ovi) and [Jean Marie](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/305862/jean-marie) have together effectively answered the question already. Unfortunately it's too long for a comment.

The reason for [Ovi's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/64460/ovi) question (presumably) is that if you're taking $\ g\ $ to be a function of the *three* variables $\ x, y, z\ $, then its graph is, by definition, the set $\ \{(x,y,z, g(x,y))\,\vert\, (x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3\,\}$, a 3-dimensional surface in the 4-dimensional space $\ \mathbb R^4\ $.  This *cannot* be a level surface of $\ f\ $, which has to be a 2-dimensional surface of the form $\ \{ (x,y,z)\,\vert\, f(x,y,z) = k\ \}$, lying in the 3-dimensional space $\ \mathbb R^3\ $.

If, on the other hand, you were to take $\ g\ $ to be a function of just the *two* variables $\ x,y\ $, then what you'd have to show would be that the set $\ \{(x,y, g(x,y))\,\vert\, (x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\,\}$ (i.e. the graph of $\ g\ $) is identical to $\ \{ (x,y,z)\,\vert\, f(x,y,z) = k\ \}$ for some value of $\ k\ $, which [Jean Marie's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/305862/jean-marie) comment is suggesting to you might be true for the value $\ k = 0\ $.

Comment: Thanks everyone!